# How to safely store Google Api keys with rails and use them in scripts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I'm trying to safely store the Google api key that I'm using in a rails project. I tried storing it in a my secrets.yml file but if I then say in my google script &key=ENV['google_api'], it can't fetch it.

I'm pretty sure this is not the way but after googling the topic, I can't really find a clear answer on this. Anyone who can offer some help?

Thanks,
Thomas

**UPDATE**, here's the code I'm using to fetch the key in my layouts file:
Issue, I'm still receiving the error that my api_key is "nil".

```
  <script>
    var GOOGLE_API_KEY="#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']}"
  </script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.23&key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']}&libraries=geometry,places&language=&hl=&region=&callback=initMap"%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to put the script call in your application.html.erb file so ruby can parse the `ENV['google_api']`. Here is an example application file (in HAML):

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Pursuit
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'
    = csrf_meta_tags

    :javascript
      var GOOGLE_API_KEY="#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']}"
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = javascript_include_tag "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']}"

  %body
    = render 'layouts/menu'
    .row
      .col.m12.l10.offset-l1
        = yield
```

Comment: My app requires access to the env variable again in the application.js file, which is why I am setting it here.

Comment: Plus, how can I do this on a viewpage? Or do you always have to mention it on the applications.html.erb?

Comment: Update, this is the script I've added with your help. However it can't identify the key and mentions apiKey = nil... Any thoughts?
<script> var GOOGLE_API_KEY="#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']}" </script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.23&key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']}&libraries=geometry,places&language=&hl=&region=&callback=initMap"%>

Comment: The application layout wraps every page, so it is available on every page. Is the key accessible to the server? Try doing this when starting up the server:
`GOOGLE_API_KEY=<KEY> rails s`

Where <KEY> is your api key (don't use the brackets). Also, can you accept the answer?

Comment: Hi, I did as you mentioned but it doesn't seem to do anything.. The key is still "nil" as my api_key still isn't recognized by Google... Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: If you start the rails console the same way `GOOGLE_API_KEY=<KEY> rails c` and then print the key `puts ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']` does it not show up?

Comment: Nope, it still gives:
2.3.0 :001 > puts ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']

 => nil

Comment: Hi, I ended up debugging a lot without any luck. In the end the issue was that I'm working with POW.cx which didn't allow the environment variable in a view. If you rendered it with local host, there were no issues at all...

Answer (score 3):

I was using the `figaro gem`. For me worked adding the environmental variable to  `application.yml` file.

```
GOOGLE_API_KEY: there_put_the_key
```

Then on top of the
`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`
(If you want to add source to all of views else you can add this line to specific view) simply add this line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=#{ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']}" %>
```